# What is a purpose of using encryption of Virtual machine in a cloud?

Tags: encryption, cloud, virtual-machine

Could you please describe some potential cases when I should use encryption of Virtual machine or some disk (storages etc.) in a cloud?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A cloud is still a data center. Somebody can steal your disks. That's why need to do encryption.